# How does $(this.hash) work?

Tags: jquery, hash

How $(this.hash) works in jQuery? I presupposed that this script should work like this - if I click to link with href tickets it will show div with id tickets. But it not works.

```
var search = $("#switcher").find("a"),
    hotels = $("#find").children("div").hide();

search.on('click', function (e) {

  $(this.hash).show()
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: be sure your div has the same href of a

exemple for a href like this  

<a href="ticketID1">Ticket 1</a>
the div must be like this

<div id="ticketID1"></div>

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`this.hash` reads the `href` attribute of `this`, and gets the part of the URL beginning with `#`. So if the anchor looks like:

```
<a href="someURL#foobar">
```

`this.hash` will be `#foobar`. When you then use `$(this.hash).show()`, it's equivalent to doing `$("#foobar").show()`, so it will show the element with `id="foobar"`.

Comment: Where  is `this.hash` documented? Google gives this page.

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash

Comment: You shouldn't be searching for `this.hash`, because it depends on what `this` is. You need to look in the documentation of the appropriate HTML element type. In this question, `this` is an `HTMLAnchorElement`. But in many applications, we use `location.hash`.

Comment: Be careful with non-ASCII characters - you may need to use `$(decodeURI(this.hash)).show()`. For example: "#VåraProdukter".