# How to use jQuery to scroll down the page slowly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to get a slow scroll effect when a button is clicked.
Now i found a  function to jump to a hash of the page when an element is clicked.

I use the scrolltop method to jump down my page.
I go -220 down the page.

Error message in the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (script.js:35)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDivElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Any help is welcome .
If you have question please ask.

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#choose-time div").on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass("selectedBox");

    if (this.hash !== '') {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;

      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 220
      }, 900);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="choose-time">
  <h2>Kies een Datum</h2>
  <div>
    <p>Donderdag</p>
    <p>28/04/2019</p>
  </div>
  <p><strong>Click</strong> de gewenste datum aan a.u.b</p>
</section>
```

Comment: You got error because of 'this.hash' is undefined and hence it got undefined in 'hash'  variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to correct hash you used. Check below link to see how hash works in jQuery.
[How does $(this.hash) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772363/how-does-this-hash-work)

Second option, you can use specific ID or Class and increase time

```
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $("#elementId").offset().top - 220
    }, 4000);
```

Comment: Thanks great answer! understanding what hash does helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code as your jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#choose-time div").on('click', function(event){
        $(this).toggleClass("selectedBox");
          var hash = $(this).offset().top - 220;
          if(hash !== ''){
            event.preventDefault();

            $("html, body").animate({
              scrollTop: hash
            }, 900);
          }
      });
    });
```